# Place images next to eachother in docx

Tags: docx, image-replacement, opentbs, tinybutstrong

```
[audit; block=begin; comm=w:p; sub1=image]
```

--PageBreak--

```
[audit_sub1; block=begin;]
```

ImageElement

```
[audit_sub1.path;ope=changepic;from=[val];default=current;adjust]
[audit_sub1; block=end;]
[audit; block=end; comm=w:p]
```

What happens in this case, is that all the images for an audit are rendered below eachother on a page. I want the images to render horizontally and continue on the next line when they reached the document width.

**Edit**

When I write everything from `[audit_sub1; block=begin;]` to `[audit_sub1; block=end;]` on one line. I get the following result:

- Image 1 is placed in top left (correct)
- Image 2 is placed next to image 1 (correct)
- Image 3 is rendered over image 1 (incorrect, I want it to render on new line because width is reached)

Comment: This should be something Word is handling based on the parameters of the ImageElement you mention. Have you tried setting the properties of the image in Word to position in-line with text?

Comment: Did you check that your image has a layout with the property Text Wrapping defined to "In line with text"?

Comment: Yes, it has the "inline with text" wrapping option. If I copy/paste the image a couple times into the document, everything goes well. Based on that I assume that the image properties are correct.

Comment: Can we have an example of your template to reproduce the problem?